# Updating value in MongoDB using ExpressJS/Mongoose

Tags: express, mongoose

I'm very new to Node.js/Express/MongoDB and the MVC approach and am having some trouble.  What I would like to do is save a user's most recent login time to MongoDB.  While prototyping, I decided to see if I could update the property dummy to the value "dummy" when the user logs in.  Here is the user schema from model/user.js:

```
var Mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = Mongoose.Schema;
var Types = Mongoose.Types;

var sUser = new Schema({
    name : String,
    hash : String,
    salt : String,
    dummy: String
});

sUser.virtual('password').set(function(pass) {
    //TODO
    this.hash = pass;
});

var mUser = Mongoose.model('user', sUser);
module.exports  = mUser;
```

I did not write this code, I'm trying to learn from it.  I tried a few things with no success.  First I thought that maybe I could update dummy using sUser.dummy.set(...) from within the model.  When I checked my hosted database on mongoHQ I did not even see the dummy property.  Next I tried fiddling with the code that executes in control/user.js when a POST occurs.  I thought that I could update dummy there when the user is created, but had no luck.  Snippet from the POST handling code below:

```
app.post("/user", function(req, res, next) {
        var u = new User(req.body);
        u.save(function(err) {
            if (err) {
                next(err);
                return;
            }

            req.session.user = u.toObject();

            if(req.accepts('html')) {
                console.log('redirect');
                res.redirect(302, '/cmd');
            } else {
                console.log(u);
                res.json(201, u);
            }
        });
    });
```

Before I go any further I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction.

What would be the best way to update the dummy field when a user logs in?

Comment: Have you tried `u.dummy = "dummy";` before save? If you want set this propery from `req.body` , create one more input field within HTML form.

Comment: I did try this and had no luck.  However, I removed all of the documents from my collection and then tried this again and it worked!  TY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did two things to solve this.  First I deleted all of the documents from the collection I tried what hawk suggested and bingo.  What was really peculiar is that I tried what hawk suggested before deleting the documents from the collection and had no luck.